# Django template tags with same name

Tags: django, templatetags

For example I have 2 templatetags

```
app1  
    templatetags  
        app1_tags.py  
            def custom_tag()  
app2  
    templatetags  
        app2_tags.py  
            def custom_tag()
```

If I load in template both templatetags

```
{% load app1_tags %}
{% load app2_tags %}
```

I have two tags with the name `custom_tag`. How can I use them in my template? Must I rename them?

Comment: I can't seem to find an answer, I'm very eager to know if this is possible.

Comment: Are both apps authored by you?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not the best solution but depending on your needs it can be helpful.

This **only works** if the **apps are made by you or if you overwrite** the template tags

This option is to give different names to each tag:

## app1_tags.py

```
@register.filter(name='custom1')
def custom_tag():
    # Your code
```

## app2_tags.py

```
@register.filter(name='custom2')
def custom_tag():
    # Your code
```

Usually if you register the tag without telling a name, Django will use the function as filter name, but if you passes the arg 'name' when you are registering the filter, Django will use that as the templatetag name.

[Django: Custom Template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters)

If you give them different names when you register the tag, that will be the name that you will use to load the tags

```
{% load custom1 %}
{% load custom2 %}
```

You only would need to customize the name of one of them, you can use the original name of the other

## Import tag under different name

As @Igor suggested, another option is to import the template you want to use with another name, let's say like an **alias** so you avoid the conflict between different tags/filters with the same name.

Assumming you want to import the tag to your project you should add your tag like:

`your_app/template_tags/my_custom_tag`

To import the tag from app2 on your app with a different name you just need to add into the file ***my_custom_tag***:

```
from app2.template_tags.app2_tags import custom_tag

register.filter(name="new_custom_tag_name", custom_tag)
```

After this you have imported the tag **custom_tag** to your project with a new name **new_custom_tag_name**

Comment: Yes, thank you. This solution is appropriate when creating custom tags. But it does not solve the problem if app1 and app2 are not my apps. It would be nice if it supports namespaces.

Comment: I tried namespaces, or renaming in the template and I couldn't make it works. This solution is only valid if the template tags are made by you or you overwrite them in your app

Comment: If both apps are not yours you can create a new template library in your app3 `app3/template_tags/my_tag`. And there you can import tag from app2 and register it with new name. `from app2.template_tags.app2_tags import custom_tag; register.filter(name="my_custom_tag", custom_tag)`

Comment: Nice, it's similar to my answer but I think is better for this issue, I will add this info to my answer if you don't mind