# How can i use both easy thumbnails and sorl-thumbnail in the same django projects yet they have the same template tags?

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-filer, easy-thumbnails

I have this project where im using `sorl-thumbnail` to resize and crop my images on the template, in the same project i happen to use `django CMS` to manage my content, the problem is Django CMS needs '`easy-thumbnails` for its `filer` app both apps use almost similar tags and i end up with this template syntax error `placeholder', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?` when i try to use Django CMS `{% placeholder 'mycontent' %}` on my template.

Comment: Can you add a template code where it has happened? I think it's because of you didn't load tag `{% load placeholder %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like others have had this issue, and it remains unsolved: [Django template tags with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229600/django-template-tags-with-same-name)

If it's feasible to give up the use of one option or another, you could try loading one tag library before the other.

If that's not feasible, you still may have to try loading one tag library before the other, but make another tag library which imports the abandoned library, and makes another, uniquely-named tag which explicitly calls the inaccessible tag

Comment: i managed to solve it by adding ` 'libraries': {
                'sorl_thumbnail': 'sorl.thumbnail.templatetags.thumbnail',
            },` to my `TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']`.

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't know that existed! For posterity, anybody looking for details, details are at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/